# Cannot escape the stuck command line

Tags: psql

This is what I am having:

```
company=# SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE id=14 LIMIT 1;


^CCancel request sent
^[[A


^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B
^CCancel request sent
^CCancel request sent
exit()
exit



^CCancel request sent
```

Tried `exit`, `exit()` and CTRL+C, but no result. Help.

Comment: I could restart everything by killing the tab, but don't want to do that in order to not run all those commands and go through steps...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```

To get the processes that are hanging/to be cancelled.

Then:

If you want to kill the process that is hanging and unresponsive
    use:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid of the process>)
```

**Or**

If you just want to cancel a process use:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid of the process>)
```

You can also check [this doc for more information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL).

Comment: Updated my answer as I accidentally gave the same command twice instead of the correct one.